# Error message: Can't ask to parameterize a member of non-generic type

Tags: spring, aspectj, vaadin, compile-time-weaving

My setup is vaadin, mybatis and spring. Now i integrated spring with vaadin with the vaadin tutorial everything works perfect.
But when i'm using @Configurable(preConstruction = true) on a custom component with a Property.ValueChangeEvent method i got the next error on compile time from aspectj.

```
[ERROR] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't ask to parameterize a member of non-generic type: com.vaadin.data.Property$ValueChangeListener  kind(simple)
```

Is there a known solution for this?

Comment: I had to upgrade aspectj to 1.7.0 to resolve this issue.

Comment: There was an AspectJ [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=298675) that looks like your issue, reported for 1.6.6, and it is at "NEW" status. I see this same error in 1.6.11 and Java 8. One note: didn't mention the version of Java, but AspectJ is not fully supported on Java 8 until 1.8.1